# PHP/HTML/SQL - Search database for a specific age and gender

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, post

Im wanting to have a multiple option for a search form when retrieving data, i've currently got something along these lines for a 1 specific search term.

```
    <form action="sRetrieveResponse.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email..." name="sRetrieveEmail">
        <input type="submit" value="Retrieve"></form>
```

Above is the html form, with the php below.

```
if($_POST['sRetrieveEmail']) 
    $queryRetrieve = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM staffData WHERE sEmail='".$_POST['sRetrieveEmail']."'" );
```

With it then being printed out onto a table, how would i make it so it finds two search terms? for example males aged 40 or above...

Another question within this is, i currently only take birthdays in a date form, how would i change this data into a age so the search term can be carried out?

Sorry if the wording doesn't make sense, im not quite sure if what im after can even be done as im quite new to programming, anything that doesnt make sense please just ask! and ill try clarify it in further depth.

Thank you.

---

Answers in comments are almost there! - the search query is sorted now, but how would i work out the age if the user is submitted their birthday, in this format: 2015-01-27.

Comment: FYI You're going to get hammered for not using `myqsli_*`

Comment: How is age stored in the database? How is it queried (from the form)?

Comment: Check my edited answer! You need to calculate age on the fly.. TIMESTAMPDIFF is the function to use.. DATEDIFF will not give you the whole year difference you are looking for

Comment: read up on SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL OR..

```
Select * FROM staffData WHERE eEmail='..' OR eGender='..'
```

If you want to match both criteria use AND instead, or you can even combine them

```
...WHERE eEmail='..' OR (eGender='..' AND 'eLastName Like '..%);
```

With regards to the age, you can create an age field in your select:

```
Select eFirstName, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, eBirthdate, CURDATE()) AS age FROM staffData WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, eBirthdate, CURDATE()) > '..';
```

Comment: I understand this, but how would i make it so its SELECT * FROM staffData where sAge is greater than 40 AND sGender = male.

Comment: @ili `sAge > 40 AND sGender='male'` It all depends how your birthday is stored.

Comment: @PanamaJack its like this, 2015-01-27

Comment: just added some info for the age.. you'll need to calculate age on the fly in your SQL

Comment: @whiteatom - how would i calculate the age? for some reason when ive had something like this <?php
$date = new DateTime($_POST['sBirthday']);
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $now->diff($date);
echo $interval->y;
?> it didnt seem to work, with a error on DateTime()

Comment: the SQL above will do that for you.. select "TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, eBirthdate, CURDATE()) AS age" as one of your fields, and you'll have age to display. If you just want to filter on it use "WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, eBirthdate, CURDATE()) > 40"

Answer (score 0):

First convert the date into age and run the query

```
 <?php
  //birth date in yyyy-mm-dd format
  $dob = "1990-01-01";

//explode the date to get year , month and day
 $dob = explode("-", $dob);


 //get age from date or birthdate
    $current_month = date("m");
    $current_day = date("j");
    $current_year = date("Y");
    $age = $current_year - $dob[0]; 
    if($current_month<$dob[1] || ($current_month==$dob[1] && $current_day<$dob[2])) $age--; 
    echo "Age is ". $age;   

?>
```

Comment: only problem with this is that i want to post the birthday from another page

Comment: can you not calculate this age in that page and post the age?